# Bootstrap 3 multiple Modal Issues

Tags: web, css, html

I have a page that i would like to open in multiple modals.  I was able to have the modal appear for id="myModal"  which was the example im trying to replicate. I created the second one with id="redcarpet" and i cannot get the same window to popup. Im hoping someone can see an error in my code and can help me fix it.

```
<li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown"
                            data-delay="200" data-close-others="false"><span style="color: black; font-family: 'Modern Regular';">PHOTOS</span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#redcarpet">Red Carpet</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span style="color: black; font-family: 'Modern Regular';">LEAD</span></a>
                        </li>
```

×
                        2015 Awards

```
        <!-- red carpet Modal -->
        <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal modal-wide fade" id="redcarpet" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="redcarpetLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="redcarpetLabel">2015 Awards</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <iframe src="redCarpet.html" width="580" height="780" frameborder="0"
                    allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    <!-- /.modal -->

<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal modal-wide fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">2015 Billboard Music Awards</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <iframe src="billboardmusicawards_lead.htm" width="580" height="780" frameborder="0"
                    allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    <!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have changed the id of the modal div container to `redcarpet` (yes, that can be seen in your code).

However, in the `data-target` attribute for the link that invokes this modal, you are still using the old id (`#myModal`):

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

Comment: Thank You Sir! I was stuck on that for weeks!! Highly appreciate it.